# Need some suggestions for zend frame work 2.5 module.config.php file

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

This my Directory Structure

```
  -> = folder
  -  = file

    wamp/www/zf2crud
    ->module
        ->Application
        ->CsnUser
            ->config
                -module.config.php
            ->language
                - ..
            ->src
                ->CsnUser
                    ->Controller
                        -UserController.php
            ->view
                ->csn-user
                    ->user
                        -create.phtml
                        -delete.phtml
                        -index.phtml
                        -update.phtml
                ->error
                    ..
                ->layout
                    ..
            -Module.php
```

I followed this tutorial to developed one module CsnUser. [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYkVHiXeGeY)   .its old version .so i copied module.config.php from my default folder Application folder. after that if i enter http://localhost/zf2crud/public/  my zend framework deafault home page work fine and enter http://localhost/zf2crud/public/csn-user  it going my CsnUser index page it also fine. but if i enter http://localhost/zf2crud/public/csn-user/user/update/ something its giving 404 error i think problem is my module.config.php

i need to go all my another view like update delete create page how to do this.

This my CsnUser config file.
module.config.php

```
    namespace CsnUser;

    return array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'csn_user' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/csn-user',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'CsnUser\Controller\user',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
                // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
                // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
                // using the path /application/:controller/:action
                'csnuser' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/csnuser',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'CsnUser\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'user',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'default' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'service_manager' => array(
            'abstract_factories' => array(
                'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
                'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
            ),
            'factories' => array(
                'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            ),
        ),
        'translator' => array(
            'locale' => 'en_US',
            'translation_file_patterns' => array(
                array(
                    'type'     => 'gettext',
                    'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                    'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
               // 'CsnUser\Controller\User' => Controller\UserController::class
                'CsnUser\Controller\user' => 'CsnUser\Controller\UserController'
            ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'display_not_found_reason' => true,
            'display_exceptions'       => true,
            'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
            'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
            'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
            'template_map' => array(
                'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
                'csn-user/user/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/csn-user/user/index.phtml',
                'csn-user/user/update' => __DIR__ . '/../view/csn-user/user/update.phtml',
                'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
                'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            ),
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),
        // Placeholder for console routes
        'console' => array(
            'router' => array(
                'routes' => array(
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** you should try to serve your application from the public folder directly. Where you now do `http://localhost/zf2crud/public/` it should actually be serving `http://localhost/` directly. You can easily fix this by configuring your vhost.

**2)** Your router config seems a bit off if you ask me, I would suggest something like this instead, I think this is what you want...

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'csnuser' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/csn-user',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'CsnUser\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'user',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

This will match as follows:

```
 url                                      controller                           action
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 http://localhost/csn-user             -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/csn-user/user        -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/csn-user/user/index  -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/csn-user/user/update -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> update
 http://localhost/csn-user/user/delete -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> delete
 http://localhost/csn-user/user/create -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> create
```

And if you introduce a new controller for example for companies:

```
 'CsnUser\Controller\company' => 'CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController'
```

You can match like this

```
 url                                         controller                              action
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 http://localhost/csn-user/company        -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> index
 http://localhost/csn-user/company/index  -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> index
 http://localhost/csn-user/company/update -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> update
 http://localhost/csn-user/company/delete -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> delete
 http://localhost/csn-user/company/create -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> create
```

---

**3)** You could also remove the whole `csn-user` part from the router. It seems a bit unnecessary...

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'CsnUser\Controller',
                        'action' => 'index'
                        'controller' => 'user'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

This will match as follows:

```
 url                             controller                           action
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 http://localhost             -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/user        -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/user/index  -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> index
 http://localhost/user/update -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> update
 http://localhost/user/delete -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> delete
 http://localhost/user/create -> CsnUser\Controller\UserController -> create
```

And if you introduce a new controller for example for companies:

```
 'CsnUser\Controller\company' => 'CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController'
```

You can match like this

```
 url                                controller                              action
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 http://localhost/company        -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> index
 http://localhost/company/index  -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> index
 http://localhost/company/update -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> update
 http://localhost/company/delete -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> delete
 http://localhost/company/create -> CsnUser\Controller\CompanyController -> create
```

---

Comment: thanks for helping .i will try and let you know that what happened

Comment: @jothi You could also remove the whole `csn-user` part from the router. It seems a bit unnecessary...

Comment: oaky i will try @Wilt

Comment: third step working perfect for what i expected .thank you so much .really thanks